A contradiction about sequences infimum

This lemma is for Cantor’s construction of real numbers in Amann and Escher's Analysis I，notion like $[s]$ represents the equivalent class of rational Cauchy sequence where equivalent relation is the difference of two sequence is null sequence.
The sentence underlined claims the inequalites chain is a contradiction，but I can’t get it，for each $k\in\mathbb N$, $s_k$ is a fixed rational number and since $s$ is strictly increasing, why would “$[s]$ is greater than the equivalent class of the constant sequence $s_k$” derive a contradiction？（where $[s]＞[q]$ is defined as sequence $s-q$ is “almost all” strictly positive).
Here are two more questions in my subsequent reading

I think the second inequality of the first sentence underlined could be equality since two possibilities of the recursive definition both implies that $β_{j+1}-α_{j+1}=（β_j-α_j）/2$.
Besides,I am confused about the last claim,we use a fixed upper bound $γ$ of $A$ to construct$(α_n)$and $(β_n)$,how can we get $α≤γ$ for all upper bound $γ$ of $A$？

Missing piece of the proof by contradiction
I think maybe we're missing ($s_k[\bar{1}]<\rho$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$) implies ($[s]\leq\rho$).
Proof: for arbitrary $k\in \mathbb{N}$, consider constant sequence $\overline{s_k}=(s_k,s_k,s_k\ldots)\in s_k[\bar{1}]$ and arbitrary sequence $t=(t_1,t_2,t_3,\ldots)\in \rho$. Since $s_k[\bar{1}]<\rho$ we have sequence $t-\overline{s_k}$ is strictly positive, meaning there is an $n_k\in\mathbb{N}$ and an $N_k\in\mathbb{N}^{\times}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ such that $t_n-s_k>\frac{1}{N_k}$ whenever $n\geq n_k$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $n_k$ is strictly increasing with $k$.
Finally, we see the subsequence of $t$ given by $(t_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}=(t_{n_1},t_{n_2},t_{n_3},\ldots)$ is also a member of equivalence class $\rho$ but also $t_{n_k}-s_k>\frac{1}{N_K}$ for all $k$ implies that sequence $(t_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}-s$ is either strictly positive or null (it could be null in the event that $\frac{1}{N_k}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$) which is to say $\left[(t_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\right]=\rho\geq [s]$. This of course contradicts
Bigger Picture
So we wanted to demonstrate that equivalence class $[s]\in R$ is precisely the least upper bound for the increasing Cauchy sequence $(\rho_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$, meaning no $\rho\in R$ exists such that $\rho<[s]$ and $\rho_k\leq \rho$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
The important takeaway of (6.5) is that the rational $s_k$ is specially constructed so that class $s_k[\bar{1}]$ is wedged in-between class $\rho_k$ and class $\rho_{k+1}$. Roughly speaking, constructing $[s]$ with $s=(s_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, is kind of like taking $\lim_{k\to \infty}s_k$ which should equal $\lim_{k\to\infty} \rho_k$ because $\rho_k<s_k<\rho_{k+1}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
So assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there existed a $\rho\in R$ such that $\rho_k\leq \rho<[s]$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. As the book states, (6.5) yields $s_k[\bar{1}]<\rho_{k+1}\leq \rho$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, which, by the logic above, yields $|s|\leq \rho$ which contradicts with our assumption that $\rho<|s|$. Thus, by contradiction, no such $\rho\in R$ exists and $|s|$ is the least upper bound for sequence $(\rho_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Greatly thanks！I didn't think out the usage of subsequence at the time，and I think the last step of the proof is roughly like “$\forall k\in\mathbb{N} x_k＞0 $then $limx_k≥0$”right?（here $x_k$is $t_{n_k}-s_k-1/N_k$）.But another question arises—Do we need axiom of choice to construct the sequence$(1/N_k)$and $(n_k)$?

About the last question in my problem,I have a rough idea,could you please have a look? Let $γ’$be an arbitrary upper bound of $A$ and suppose $γ’＜α$,then $γ’$isn't a upper bound of $(α_j)$,which means there is a $j\in\mathbb{N}$satisfies $α_j＞γ’$,from the recursive definition,if $α_j$is the first situation,that is there is an $a\in A$ with $a≥γ_{j-1}$,we will have $γ’＜α_j=γ_{j-1}≤a$ that contradicts γ’ is an upper bound of $A$,if $α_j$ is the other situation then $α_j=α_{j-1}＞γ’$,so this allow us to repeat the above logic,so if the process ends at a step in middle,it means a contradiction

else we will get $α_0＞γ’$,but since $α_0\in A$,It is also a contradiction
